# biOps jpeg image reading [R]

Tags: r

I want to read an Jpeg image in R. Transform it into greyscale and finally to get the Negative of the image.

I used to read the image with biOps and then make the other two transformations with EBImage.

Currently I am working with windows 8 and I cannot make this simple actions anymore, due to version issues I think.

I would like to install the correct packages or to find some other way to do this three simple steps.

Thank u!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to read the file in with `biOps`? (which is no longer available on CRAN)

```
#Read the file in with `EBImage`
library("EBImage")
your_image = readImage(system.file("directory", "your_image.jpg", package="EBImage"))
#perform your other transformations
```